# Adblock prevents my call to Indeed API

Tags: adblock

I'm doing a project that employs an API call to Indeed.com.

When adblock is enabled, it does not work, with an error message in the chrome dev console:

```
 "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT"
```

This is followed by the Indeed.com api call URL.

Anyone else have experience with adblock shutting down API calls?

Any ideas for a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details on the call URL?

Comment: It's been a while, I think the problem resolved itself, thanks though.